# How can I view the photos on my website from facebook using Javascript?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, photos

I have a page on facebook. https://www.facebook.com/pages/2playcz-Tenisov%C3%A1-%C5%A1kola/190320081093741

I would like to view photos on my website using ajax.

How can I view the photos on the my website using javascript?

I tried this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

   $(function() {
    $.post('https://graph.facebook.com/190322704426812/photos',{

        }, function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    //alert(key + ': ' + value);
});
 },"json");

});
    </script>
```

DATA:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "190322817760134",
         "from": {
            "name": "2play.cz - Tenisov\u00e1 \u0161kola",
            "category": "Sports league",
            "id": "190320081093741"
         },
         "picture": "http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/303504_190322817760134_142853251_s.jpg",
         "source": "http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/303504_190322817760134_142853251_n.jpg",
         "height": 149,
         "width": 187,
         "images": [
            {
               "height": 1631,
               "width": 2048,
               "source": "http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s2048x2048/303504_190322817760134_142853251_n.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 149,
               "width": 187,
               "source": "http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/303504_190322817760134_142853251_n.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 149,
               "width": 187,
               "source": "http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/303504_190322817760134_142853251_n.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 382,
               "width": 480,
               "source": "http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s480x480/303504_190322817760134_142853251_n.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 254,
               "width": 320,
               "source": "http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s320x320/303504_190322817760134_142853251_n.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 143,
               "width": 180,
               "source": "http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/303504_190322817760134_142853251_a.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 103,
               "width": 130,
               "source": "http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/303504_190322817760134_142853251_s.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 103,
               "width": 130,
               "source": "http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s75x225/303504_190322817760134_142853251_s.jpg"
            }
         ],
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=190322817760134&set=a.190322704426812.39225.190320081093741&type=1",
         "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
         "created_time": "2012-06-09T13:34:24+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-06-09T13:34:25+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/190322704426812/photos?value=1&redirect=1&limit=25&after=MTkwMzIyODE3NzYwMTM0"
   }
}
```

There was an error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 102
   }
}
```

I need to read the following line:

```
"picture": "http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/303504_190322817760134_142853251_s.jpg"
"source": "http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/303504_190322817760134_142853251_n.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using $.post when it should be $.get. Check this out. is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/gz9HJ/